# The best way for storing 2D game map

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm implementing Bomberman clone in Java. Its map has a scale of 17*13 tiles. Now I'm storing the game map in the `ArrayList`. Obviously it's unproductive since game mechanics provides only discrete moving (right, left, up, down). Bombs can have only discrete position too. So with the `ArrayList` I have to look for four adjacent tiles through whole list while processing collisions or fire generating. So what are the best practices for storing such maps in Java.

Comment: Please, feel free to edit this question, if there are any grammar mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways you could model this. Here's a suggestion that I've used often for similar problems:

```
enum Direction {
    NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST;
}

class Position {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public static Stream<Position> getAllPositions();
    public Stream<Position> getNeighbours();
    public Optional<Position> positionInDirection(Direction direction);

    // make sure you implement equals and hashCode
}

class Map {
    private final Map<Position, Tile> tiles = new HashMap<>();

    public Map() {
        Position.getAllPositions().forEach(pos -> tiles.put(pos, new Tile());
    }

    public Tile getTile(Position position) {
        return tiles.get(position);
    }
}
```

This provides lots of useful encapsulation. For example the `Position` class is the only one that needs to know about the size of the map and edges.

Now to see if an adjacent position has a bomb (for example), you would use:

```
position.getNeighbours().map(map::getTile).anyMatch(Tile::hasBomb);
```